# How to add notification count on one of my tab bar on page sliding tabstrip

Tags: android

below is my code:

```
mViewPager = (CustomViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPagerFeed);

mViewPager.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
mViewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPageAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), fragments));
mViewPager.setScrollable(true);

SptPagerSlidingTabStrip pagerSlidingTabStrip = (SptPagerSlidingTabStrip) view.findViewById(R.id.pagerSlidingTabStrip1);
pagerSlidingTabStrip.setViewPager(mViewPager);

LinearLayout v = (LinearLayout) pagerSlidingTabStrip.getChildAt(0);
TextView textView = (TextView) v.getChildAt(1);
String count = MessegeDetail.count;

textView.setText("MESSEGES"+"-"+count);

return view;
```

Comment: bro, add this code below **textView** `Log.d("APP_TEST", "" + textView);` and tell me what's the output, is it null or it contains textView identifier?

Comment: the output in log is MESSEGES-2  2 is the no. of count

Comment: I want the notification so what should I can do in my customised class sptpagerslidingtabstrip it is a class just like pagersliding tabstrip

Comment: did you try changing `v.getChildAt(1);` to `v.getChildAt(0);` ?